# Are temperature and chemical potential of a black hole independent quantities?

Tags: statistical-mechanics, black-holes, temperature, ads-cft, chemical-potential

I am a bit confused about the *independent* parameters in a charged black hole in AdS spaces. From equation (63) of this [lecture notes](https://arxiv.org/abs/0903.3246) we see that the temperature ($T$) of the black hole has chemical potential ($\mu$) dependence.

1. I was wondering, if one wishes to work in this background (using holography) what are the free parameters one can play with?
2. What are the basic differences between canonical and grand canonical ensemble description of this system? Also which ensemble should one choose to work with depending on the problem?

EDIT :

3. What does $\mu \to 0$ mean? Here it seems like charge-free limit. But this limit appears also in Bose-Einstein condensate. Isn't this a bit subtle?

Comment: In principle you have $T$ and $\mu$ as parameters, but only the $T/\mu$ dependence is nontrivial since this is dimensionless. E.g. if $X$ is some quantity with (scaling) dimension $\delta$, you can write $X=X(T,\mu)$ but also $X=X(\frac{T}{\mu},\mu)$. Dimensional analysis then makes the $\mu$ dependence trivial, i.e. $X=f(T/\mu)\mu^\delta$, and you're only left with a function depending on $T/\mu$.

Comment: In the canonical ensemble you would use the charge density $\rho$ rather than $\mu$ as a parameter and consider the $T/\sqrt{\rho}$ dependence (for 3+1 bulk dimensions) of $X$. I guess the choice of ensemble depends on what you want to describe in the boundary theory

Comment: @ScroogeMcDuck Thanks a lot for your response! But why do you think they are two independent parameters?

Comment: @ScroogeMcDuck Can you also elaborate on the second comment, I mean, some example of boundary theories in this context..

Comment: Simply because if I fix the chemical potential, I can still change the temperature. There's still $r_+$. Yes, you can scale to $r_+=1$, but that basically just implies you're considering quantities $\tilde{T}=Tr_+$ and $\tilde{\mu}=\mu r_+$ instead of the physical $T$ and $\mu$. Indeed, then $\tilde{\mu}$ fixes $\tilde{T}$. But I can still fix the physical $\mu$ and change $\tilde{\mu}$ (by changing $r_+$), thereby changing $\tilde{T}$ through (63).

Comment: For the ensemble thing, I'm not entirely sure. Taking the holographic superconductor as an example, I know that you can treat it in either of the ensembles, but there might be some condensed matter systems that can be described with a boundary theory for which a fixed chemical potential makes more sense than a fixed density.

Comment: @ScroogeMcDuck thanks a lot for the comments! Here is my very specific question. Suppose I had a strongly coupled system whose dual theory is described by a AdS-BH. Now if I am interested in physical quantities, e.g, green function, in small frequency regime (say) I can expand them in $\omega \over T$. But once I introduce charge to the BH what should be my expansion parameters? I want to get back my old results by taking the charge or chemical potential to zero.

Comment: I have added one more related question. It might be a bit silly.